# HashTable without Collections Library

Tags: java, arrays, oop, hashmap, hashtable

I am trying to create a basic file system. I am not allowed to use `Collections` library. This file system stores 2 types of data `Files` and `Directories`. Types `File` and `Directory` are both subclasses of abstract type `Entry`.

My design so far

My hash function is to take the name of the `Entry` and convert each char in the name into an integer and sum them up to one value. Next mod the value with the size of the array to determine where it is placed

```
protected static int hashFunction(String entryName) {
        char[] a = entryName.toCharArray();
        int sum = 0;
        // convert String to integer Value
        for (char b : a) {
            sum += (int) b;
        }
        int hashValue = sum % hashTableKey;
        return hashValue;
    }
```

What I am having trouble is designing the hash table. Currently, once the hash function computes the value, I store the name of the `Entry` (`entryName`) in an array relative to the `hashVaue`. I store the actual objects in another array of same size to hold these objects. The storage of these objects have the same index as their respective names in the array the hold the object's names.

*Objects can be either file or directory

```
| "obj1" | None | "obj3" | None | None | None | "obj2" | None |

| obj1 | None | obj3 | None | None | None | obj2 | None |
```

Not sure if this is a good way to implement a file system using a hashtable. The reason why I chose a hashtable is due to the O(1) look ups. However it has a big space requirement. Especially the way I implemented it. If there is a better way to implement a file system please let me know! I am open to ideas!!

Comment: Why don't you just call `entryName.hashCode()` to get a hash code, out of interest? And if this is just an academic exercise (which I assume it is, if you can't use the standard collections) is the O(1) lookup really a requirement?

Comment: @JonSkeet This does seem like homework but I am actually learning Java by studying and practicing interview questions. I forgot about `hashCode()`. Not sure how it works but I can look it up. My guess is to mod the result of using hashCode() with size to place in the correct place? I wanted to do O(1) because it looks good on interviews haha

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should have the other array, you could either store the actual object in the first array, because the Entity will know about it's name so sanity checking when selecting an element is easy.

Although what I see as a design flaw, unless I misunderstood something, is that you actually prone to errors when two files have the same hash code which here is entirelly possible because you can only store as many objects as many keys there are in your hashtable.

How it is usually solved is that instead of having an array of Strings and Entities you should have an array of LinkedList (well, your implementation of a linked list since you cannot use Collections) and store the Entities in the lists, this will make your performance reliant on how good your hash function is,but this will lessen the required space also, although not much. That's how actually Java's hash map works more or less.

Just on a personal note, I really don't like to depend on two arrays having the same objects on the same index, it's just very error prone.

Comment: I havent created a method to deal with collisions yet. I was planning to just increment by 1 and placing the object and String in the next index if the array that stored the entryNames contained a name already

Comment: That's one way to deal with it but then you'd have to deal with the fact that what happened if you had a collision at i with element 'a' and 'b' , then you add your item 'b' to i+1, but after there will be an item 'b' with the hash code of i+1, so you put it to i+1, then you will have to look up the 'c' item you'll look at i+1, in which case you won't find it, okay look at i+2. This could escalate and mess up your performance and your code will look ugly :)